# Can I delete my Google Photos folder from my Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

I enabled and then later disabled the feature to show a Google Photos folder inside my Google Drive. I decided to just use the Google Photos app directly, so I no longer want to see this folder.

[image]

But, it seems to have left the folder behind in my Google Drive. This is days later, so I'm not sure if it's still "working on it."

[image]

Is this safe to delete?

Comment: I'd try testing it by renaming it to something else and see if Google Photos still functions correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have disabled the feature to show Google Photos folder inside my Google Drive.

Now you can delete Google Photos folder from the Drive. It is safe. It will not delete photos from Google Photos.

<sup>Source: Self tested.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Just tried this myself and just as the dialog says, it will indeed delete the files from Google Photos as well. I checked and I have the option turned off to have photos added to a Google Drive folder. I just deleted files that were there from when I still had the option on. After a while I refreshed photos.google.com and the files were gone!

[image: image delete warning]

Comment: If you are taking backup of Google Photos in Drive and then if you delete photos from Drive, it will delete from Google Photos also. Disable the feature to show Google Photos folder inside Google Drive, after that it will not remove photos from Google Photos.

Answer (score 1):

> If you delete folders (including the Google Photos folder), photos and
>   videos won’t be deleted in Google Photos. This is to avoid deleting
>   all your photos and videos by accident.

(If you delete photos individually, its different).

Source: Google
https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Comment: Nice! And welcome to WebApps. Please quote a bit from the source link to improve the answer (in case the link will change, and for answer completeness).

Answer (score -1):

problem is once you delete this folder from drive the day you delete folder the old picture will not come back there again, only new picture after delete date will come back. is you decide do download them again you in trouble. So google crazy as usual, and there no solution ...